# How do I download android source?

Tags: apt, package-management, android

I am new to Ubuntu and currently using 20.04.

I am trying to perform this command from [this guide on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/baylibre/amlogic/atv/aosp/device/amlogic/yukawa/-/wikis/Khadas_VIM3):

```
sudo repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
```

I have determined I need a package installed called `repo` to do this.

So I tried to install it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install repo

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package repo
```

I am stuck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The `repo` package is not in Ubuntu 20.04. It's in 18.04 and 20.10. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=repo for more information.

Comment: Thnx, the simple things that can hang up a new user and send them into the "why am I trying this again?"  doldrums...